# Bash: smarter way to generate a sequence of digit-alphabet combination?

Tags: bash, sequence

Are there smarter ways (I am pretty sure there are) than the code below to obtain a sequence of digits with leading zero, accompanied by a alphabet starting from 'c'?

```
$ paste <(echo {01..10}|tr ' ' \\n) <(echo {c..l}|tr ' ' \\n) | sed 's/\t//g'
01c
02d
03e
04f
05g
06h
07i
08j
09k
10l
```

Comment: That's pretty clever, but not so efficient. Look at `awk` with nested for-loops and soemthing like `printf("%02d%s\n", numVar, charVar)`. It is possiblte to to similar with `printf` in raw `bash`. Good luck.

Comment: Er... I think you took the question differently.  I need the output exactly as shown above.  Your suggestion seems to show all the combinations specified range of digits and character which I do not want.  BTW, my awk code did not work: `awk '{n=1;c="c"; for(i=0;i<10;i++){printf("%02d%s\n",n++,c++)}}'< /dev/null`  Could you point out what's wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to solve your problem in a comment, but just to point you to the general idea of an awk solution. but ... here you go ... `awk 'END{n=1;c=99; for(i=0;i<10;i++){printf("%02d%c\n",n++,c++)}}' /dev/null` . You could also write functions `i2c` (int2char), etc OR they may be out there somewhere already. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

add_num(){
  local n=1
  local f

  for f; do
    printf '%02d%s\n' $((n++)) "$f"
  done
}

add_num {c..l}
```

The function/code above is not limited to just `{c..l}` it can be `{a..z}` or even an array.

According to `help for`

```
for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
    Execute commands for each member in a list.
    
    The `for' loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
    list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is
    assumed.  For each element in WORDS, NAME is set to that element, and
    the COMMANDS are executed.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

So the `for` loop inside the function the `in WORDS...;` is omitted. It is the same thing as `for f in "$@"; do ...; done` according to the `help` where `"$@"` expands to all the positional parameter, e.g. `"$1"`, `"$2"`, `"$3"` and so on.

See `help printf` and `help local`

`man 1p printf` (if availabe) has a more detailed explanation than `help` and in `man bash`

See also `Arithmetic Expansion` and `Arithmetic Evaluation` in `man bash` for the `$((n++))`.

Comment: Nicely done. May be worth explaining how in `for name [in [word ... ] ]` if `in word` is omitted, the `for` command executes once for each positional parameter...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you sir for the comment, added some explanation.

Comment: Wow, this is impressive and smart! I rewrote it into one liner: `n=1; for f in {c..l};do printf "%02d%s\n" $((n++)) $f; done`

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -e '
    $n = "01"; $a = "c";
    for (1 .. 10) {
        printf "%s%s\n", $n++, $a++;
    }
'
```

Comment: Sounds neat, but it did not work out.  I modified the code as:
`perl -e '$n="01"; $a="c"; print $n++,$a++,"\n" for 1..10;'`
This worked just right. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am not sure why my code does not work but your modification is quite reasonable.

Comment: `n` option bothers. The rest was just fine.  ;-)

Comment: Oops! Absolutely right. I've fixed my answer :)